# limit the msgbox input size equal to 20

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, msgbox

```
$.msgbox("Editar Contato", {
                type: "prompt",
                inputs: [
                  { type: "text", id: "txtname", label: "Nome:", value: nome, required: true,maxlength: "20" },
                  { type: "email", id: "txtemail", label: "Email:", value: email, required: true,maxlength: "20" },
                  { type: "text", id: "txttelipho1", label: "Telefone 1:", value: teliphone1, required: true, maxlength: "20" },
                  { type: "text", id: "txttelipho2", label: "Telefone 2:", value: teliphone2, required: true, maxlength: "20" }
                ],
                buttons: [
                  { type: "submit", value: "Salvar" },
                  { type: "cancel", value: "Cancelar" }
                ]
```

Above code shows my input of msgbox, and input field in database takes limited charecter as 20 then how can i stop to the user do not enter more than 20 charecter in inputs field of msgbox

i used maxlength but it is not prevent to enter more than 20 charterers inside the input

thanks ........

Comment: using maxlength is a good way

Answer (score 0):

you can use `maxlength` attribute to set maxlength propert to textbox.Something like this:

```
 { type: "text",
 id: "txtname",
 label: "Nome:",
 value: nome,
 required: true,
 maxlength:"20" },
```

**For msgbox:**

```
$.msgbox("Editar Contato", {

type: "prompt",
inputs: [
  { type: "text", id: "txtname", label: "Nome:", value: nome, required: true,maxlength:"20" },
  { type: "email", id: "txtemail", label: "Email:", value: email, required: true },
  { type: "text", id: "txttelipho1", label: "Telefone 1:", value: teliphone1, required: true,maxlength:"20" },
  { type: "text", id: "txttelipho2", label: "Telefone 2:", value: teliphone2, required: true,maxlength:"20" }
],
buttons: [
  { type: "submit", value: "Salvar" },
  { type: "cancel", value: "Cancelar" }
]
```

Comment: @user3442594:can you create problem fiddle.